# What is the reason for the error "The input line is too long" on running my batch file?

Tags: batch-file

This bat file worked yesterday. Now it plays dumb.

```
The input line is too long.
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

I cut the code to be sure this line is the problem.

```
ECHO activating VS cmd prompt && CALL "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" amd64
```

I tried using a variable

```
%VCVARS14_DIR%\vcvarsall.bat

"%VCVARS14_DIR%\vcvarsall.bat"
```

None of these work.
One minute, I get ...

```
The Path is not recognized.
```

The next minute, I get ...

```
The input line is too long.
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

This is so frustrating.
How can I fix this problem?

Here is the batch file:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET EL=0

ECHO ~~~~~~ %~f0 ~~~~~~

SET

ECHO activating VS cmd prompt && CALL "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" amd64
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 GOTO ERROR

CD ..

nuget install expat.v140 -Version 2.2.5
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 GOTO ERROR

SET PATH=C:/projects/expat.v140.2.2.5/build/native/bin/x64/%config%;%PATH%

nuget install zlib-vc140-static-64 -Version 1.2.11
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 GOTO ERROR

nuget install bzip2.v140 -Version 1.0.6.9
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 GOTO ERROR

SET PATH=C:/projects/bzip2.v140.1.0.6.9/build/native/bin/x64/%config%;%PATH%

CD osmium-tool

ECHO config^: %config%

SET libpostfix=""
IF "%config%"=="Debug" SET libpostfix="d"

IF EXIST build ECHO deleting build dir... && RD /Q /S build
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 GOTO ERROR

MKDIR build
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 GOTO ERROR

CD build

SET CMAKE_CMD=cmake .. -LA -G "Visual Studio 14 Win64" ^
-DOsmium_DEBUG=TRUE ^
-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=%config% ^
-DBOOST_ROOT=C:/Libraries/boost_1_63_0 ^
-DZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR=C:/projects/zlib-vc140-static-64.1.2.11/lib/native/include ^
-DZLIB_LIBRARY=C:/projects/zlib-vc140-static-64.1.2.11/lib/native/libs/x64/static/%config%/zlibstatic.lib ^
-DEXPAT_INCLUDE_DIR=C:/projects/expat.v140.2.2.5/build/native/include ^
-DEXPAT_LIBRARY=C:/projects/expat.v140.2.2.5/build/native/lib/x64/%config%/libexpat%libpostfix%.lib ^
-DBZIP2_INCLUDE_DIR=C:/projects/bzip2.v140.1.0.6.9/build/native/include ^
-DBZIP2_LIBRARIES=C:/projects/bzip2.v140.1.0.6.9/build/native/lib/x64/%config%/libbz2%libpostfix%.lib ^
-DBoost_USE_STATIC_LIBS=ON

ECHO calling^: %CMAKE_CMD%
%CMAKE_CMD%
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 GOTO ERROR

msbuild osmium.sln ^
/p:Configuration=%config% ^
/toolsversion:14.0 ^
/p:Platform=x64 ^
/p:PlatformToolset=v140
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 GOTO ERROR

ctest --output-on-failure -C %config%
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 GOTO ERROR

GOTO DONE

:ERROR
ECHO ~~~~~~ ERROR %~f0 ~~~~~~
SET EL=%ERRORLEVEL%

:DONE
IF %EL% NEQ 0 ECHO. && ECHO !!! ERRORLEVEL^: %EL% !!! && ECHO.
ECHO ~~~~~~ DONE %~f0 ~~~~~~

EXIT /b %EL%
```

Comment: You get `The input line is too long` when you try to do something with a variable that's longer than 8192 characters. You generally only hit this if you're doing something weird with `%PATH%` or you've got an infinite loop somewhere. You cut to the wrong line, because I don't have enough information to know what's breaking.

Comment: I know it's nothing I did, because I didn't touch the Path variable since trying to build this.

Comment: It worked yesterday. The only problem I was having was with cmake and boost. When I run the build today, after installing a later version of boost... Oh wait. I did change the value of BOOST_ROOT, but that's all. That should not cause a problem. The build does set some variables though, so maybe it messed with its self. I hate builds like these... that give gripe. I just built vtk without one single complaint.

Comment: Hard to troubleshoot someone's code when the code that is posted does not produce the same result as you are describing.  Please read [mcve].

Comment: Have you installed anything between the last time this worked and now? That would potentially mess with `%PATH%`. Beyond that, I'm going to need to see the contents of vcvarsall.bat and know the value of `%VCVARS14_DIR%`.

Comment: I'm sorry about that. I was going to include the code, but forgot. I'll do that now. It's not long.

Comment: I added the link to the batch file in th OP. I am thinking, of setting the variables in the batch file manually, and then try building with cmake. I got errors yesterday, when doing that, but maybe setting the variables will make a difference. It worth a try. You think?

Comment: Oh, I don't recall installing any applications. VCVARS14_DIR just points to the directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\

Comment: Edit the `vcvarsall.bat`, replace `echo off` with `echo on` and echo the path variable at the beginning and after each modification

Comment: Can you please explain why exactly I am editing a Microsoft VS toolset. Isn't the problem with the build-appveyor batch file? Do you have reason to believe vcvarsall.bat has been altered?